# Sharepoint 2013 Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource. - get_siteGroups()

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Here is my Javascript code to get all the users from a sharepoint 2013 (office 365). But I get a error what I don't have permissions. Am I missing a trick?

It is used in a sharepoint hosted APP.

```
    function retrieveAllUsersAllGroups() {

    var clientContext = Context;
    this.collGroup = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    clientContext.load(collGroup);
    clientContext.load(collGroup, 'Include(Users)');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    var userInfo = '';

    var groupEnumerator = collGroup.getEnumerator();
    while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oGroup = groupEnumerator.get_current();
        var collUser = oGroup.get_users();
        var userEnumerator = collUser.getEnumerator();
        while (userEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oUser = userEnumerator.get_current();
            this.userInfo += '\nGroup ID: ' + oGroup.get_id() +
                '\nGroup Title: ' + oGroup.get_title() +
                '\nUser: ' + oUser.get_title() +
                '\nLogin Name: ' + oUser.get_loginName();
        }
    }

    alert(userInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PersonProperties object to get info about SharePoint users, such as display name, email, title, and other business and personal information.